# I get an error on line1 but all i do with it is to use with

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
WITH NumberedMyTable AS(
select top 50
    isnull(Project, '') Project,
    isnull(PRDesc, '') PRDesc, 
    isnull(PRNum, 0) PRNum,
    isnull(PRLine, 0) PRLine,
    isnull(Quantity, '') Quantity,
    isnull(Balance,'NO REF') [Balance],
    isnull(Unit,  '') Unit,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Project) AS RowNumber
FROM [SYSMGT].[dbo].[vw_PRItemBalance]
where Project like '%one%'
order by Project)

Select * 
from NumberedMyTable 
where Rownumber between 0 and 10
```

The problem is, i get an error that says:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

vw_PRItemBalance is a view i made in sql server 2014 management studio

Comment: What is the data type of `Balance`? With a name like that, I would guess not a numerical data type? Also, you have `isnull(Quantity, '') Quantity,`. If `Quantity` has a value of `NULL` then `''` will be implicitly converted to a `int` (assume `Quantity` is an `int`). which will be `0` (Try `SELECT CONVERT(int,'');`). You should really avoid mixing data types in your RDBMS. If you have to handle them, do so in the presentation layer.

Comment: the error should be coming from `isnull(Quantity, '')` or `isnull(Balance,'NO REF')` or both. `Quantity` and `Balance` looks like a numeric data type and you are trying to convert the string `''` and `NO_REF` to numeric. That causes the error

Comment: the quantity and balance are both varchar(max)

Comment: The reported line number is the line (counting from the start of the batch or from the line containing the `CREATE` for procedure definitions) where the *statement* starts. It's identifying the multi-line statement that starts on line 1. It doesn't attempt to determine line numbers *within* the statement to further localize the source of the problem.

Comment: And it could be any of the columns where you use `ISNULL(<something>,'')` - `CONVERT(numeric,'')` returns the same error message. Without having the view definition in front of us, *we* cannot tell you which column is the problem

Comment: I guess `PRNum` and `PRLine` are `varchar`s as well. And they cannot be converter to int, so turn `isnull(PRNum, 0) ` into `isnull(PRNum, '0') ` to fix that.

Comment: @IvanStarostin - `ISNULL` uses the type of its first argument, not the normal type precedence rules, so `ISNULL(<some string type>,0)` is fine.

Comment: Why are you storing something called quantity (which is clearly going to be a numerical value), as a `varchar(MAX)`? That could store a number with over **2 BILLION**  characters in.

Comment: where Project like '%one%'

when i change the value to center,
where Project like '%center%'

it is successful

Comment: Sounds like the problem is your view, not your SQL query above. If you simple run `SELECT * FROM [SYSMGT].[dbo].[vw_PRItemBalance]
where Project like '%one%'
order by Project` do you get the error too?

Answer (score 0):

Just verify below columns:
These columns must be VARCHAR Type. If anyone not, then change with ISNULL(Col, 0)

```
   isnull(Project, '') Project,
    isnull(PRDesc, '') PRDesc,
    isnull(Quantity, '') Quantity,
    isnull(Balance,'NO REF') [Balance],
    isnull(Unit,  '') Unit,
```

These all are must be integer Type, If anyone not, then change it with ISNULL(col, '')

```
isnull(PRNum, 0) PRNum,
isnull(PRLine, 0) PRLine,
```

Comment: PRNum and PRLine are both integer

Comment: You assume that project doesnt have varchar value, but try your same example with this one, you will get same error.

WITH V 
AS(
SELECT 1 i 
UNION 
SELECT NULL
UNION
SELECT 'A') 

SELECT ISNULL(i,'') FROM V;

Comment: That isn't the same @JERRY. a table with the value `'A'` could never exist if the column has the datatype `int`.

Comment: @Larnu - the error message says `numeric`, not `int`. Try the script from your first comment here using `numeric` instead of `int` and you'll get an error. The empty string doesn't convert without error to *numeric*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ahh, yes, you're right. `WITH V AS(SELECT 1.0 i UNION SELECT NULL) SELECT ISNULL(i,'') FROM V;` does indeed fail.